# prevent apache from processing urls

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want apache to rewrite everything to my index.php, meaning that apache should not process anything, it should ignore the url input and just forward it to the index.php.

I've searched for this many times, and the best solution I found was:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

But today I noticed that if I enter an existing path, apache will show the forbidden page and I don't want that. What I want is to always show the index.php whatever the uri is (obviously the part behind the domain name :P).

I'm using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to let PHP route everything, using a MVC app, so apache trying to process the url input is very conflicting.

I disabled the indexing, and I'm also thinking on denying access to the document root and allowing only the folder where the index.php is:

httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/srv/http">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    #Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/

    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/example.com/www"
    <Directory "/srv/http/example.com/www">
        Require all granted
        <Files "index.php">
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.example.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
        </Files>

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I even want to only allow access to the index.php file, but maybe this is overkill?

Moving `Require all granted` inside the `<Files>` block does not work, but this is secondary and you'd probably discourage me from trying (probably is not even possible, or necessary).

So, how can I prevent apache from processing the urls? To let my MVC app take care of the routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the rewrite code you are using specifically excludes existing URLs, so just stop that. You don't need the `RewriteBase` either.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you need more, let me know, but looks like that should put you on the right track for what you're trying to achieve. Don't you have any image files, CSS and such you want Apache to serve itself? That's the usual reason for excluding existing URLs.

Comment: Yes, ofc, I have static files, but they're being served separately by a subdomain (static.domain.com) with the default handler for every file (that way is more secure, or so I think).

Comment: Is still showing forbidden for /.htxxx files (non-existing ones) but I guess I'll have to live with that (unless you know a way for this too), it's actually not a big deal. About the other matter, using `Require all denied` in parent folders and `Require all granted` in the vhost doc root or even only allow (if possible) the index.php, is this overkill or not necessary/possible? I just want the most secure configuration. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about showing forbidden for `/.htxxx`. If you mean files beginning `.ht` then those are forbidden by the default Apache config, in the main config, to prevent `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files being viewed. Rather than using mod_rewrite, have you considered just having the `SetHandler` applied to every URL? You could just put it in the `<Directory>` block and pass everything that way.

Comment: Regarding what to deny, if you stick with the mod_rewrite method, yes you could block everything but `index.php` if you like. Can't hurt. But it's your file system permissions that really make the difference, rather than what you allow in Apache. It's your PHP script that is likely to get broken in to, not Apache which is directing everything to your script anyway, so activity needs to be contained if that happens by keeping your file systems permissions carefully maintained.

Comment: Interesting, so can I disable mod_rewrite and use that other method? I don't know how to do that, would you mind adding an example (with link) to your answer? The other thing, so if the permissions are fine, and the http user only has access to what it is inside the doc root, anything will be fine then? Yes, the php script can be vulnerable, but I'm constantly learning more about php security and updating when I learn something new. Ty!

Comment: Sorry, no, you can't. I was half asleep and thinking you were proxying requests. The way you're doing it is good.

Comment: Getting rid of mod_rewrite? Too good to be true hehehe. Thanks anyways!